# Org-mode export filter all headlines matching pattern and promote subheaders

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a large org file containing all my notes from a course at my university this semester. Each section contains two level-three headers called "Screenings" and "Readings". When calling `org-export-to-pdf`, I'd like to filter out all these headings and promote the subheadings of these sections recursively (likely a recursive call to `org-do-promote`).

While the org mode manual is typically an excellent resource for this kind of thing, I'm finding the [Advanced Configuration](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Advanced-configuration) section to be a little brief in detail for the young, blossoming org-mode user (aka me) to grasp fully. If the more experienced Emacs user could kindly guide me in the right direction for constructing this function, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've hacked something together using the documentation on `org-map-entries` ([Using the mapping API](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Using-the-mapping-API)) and the hook example in the [Advanced Configuration](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Advanced-configuration) section of the manual.

```
(defun promote-screenings-and-readings (&optional backend)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (let ((point (point))
           (heading
            (buffer-substring-no-properties
             (point)
             (save-excursion
               (forward-line)
               (point)))))
       (when
           (or
            (string= heading "*** Screenings\n")
            (string= heading "*** Readings\n"))
         (org-map-entries
          (lambda ()
            (unless (= (point) point)
              (org-promote)))
          nil
          'tree)
         (forward-line)
         (delete-region point (point)))))))


(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'promote-screenings-and-readings)
```

`promote-screenings-and-readings` promotes all entries in the subtree *except* the root of the subtree and then deletes the heading. E.g running it on the file

```
* Foo
** Bar
*** Screenings
**** A
***** D
**** B
**** C
```

produces

```
* Foo
** Bar
*** A
**** D
*** B
*** C
```

Caveat: `promote-screenings-and-readings` only removes the header, not content that is written under it, but before the first Screening or Reading. If you need that, simply return `(point)` from the lambda and instead of forwarding the line, use the minimal point (if it exists).

Comment: Why not use  _ignore_  tag, [ox-extra ignore tag](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17677/2064)

Comment: A few reasons: First, this solution makes use of the features mentioned by the poster of the question, thus not only solving the immediate problem, but potentially also helping them learn. Second, `ox-extra` requires org version 8.3, as mentioned in your link, while earlier Emacsen (in which this solution works nonetheless) ship 8.2 at best. Third, even newer Emacsen don't ship org-contrib (which contains `ox-extra`) by default. While many happily accept, that they have to install org twice, I personally would rather not do so unless it is really needed.